# my Application is not showing on Indian store even it's selected?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have selected all territory still the app is not available on Indian store.
As I am new to this I don't know that much.

Comment: how long back app released ? check after 24hrs of release.

Comment: Thnks now its showing